# Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN date and date

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I created a partition projection in Athena named 'dt', which is a STRING and contains date information in the format `2020/12/11/20`.

I'm running the following query in Athena

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m') as dt,
    count(*) as "total_visualization",
    count(*)/cast(date_format(DATE '{END_DATE}', '%d') as integer) as "average_dia"
FROM 
    user.dashborad
WHERE 
    event = 'complete' 
    AND dt BETWEEN DATE '{START_DATE}' and DATE '{END_DATE}'
GROUP BY 1;
```

The resulting raw query received by Athena is:

```
    DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m') as dt,
    count(*) as "total_visualization",
    count(*)/cast(date_format(DATE '2022-08-08', '%d') as integer) as "average_day"
 FROM user.dashborad
 WHERE event = 'complete' AND dt BETWEEN DATE '2022-08-01' and DATE '2022-08-08'
 GROUP BY 1;
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error querying the database: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:62: Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN date and date.

I've tried to find a workaround in an attempt to convert it into a date format using date_parse but it didn't work. And with `str_to_date` I get this error:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:2: Function str_to_date not registered

Is there any other way I can modify the query to convert 'dt' from a varchar into a format Athena understands?

Comment: If `dt` is in string format you need str_to_date to convert to proper date not DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Try using CONVERT(dt, DATE) instead of DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: Change the alias name to something else like `DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m') as dt_formatted`

Comment: What does the typeof(DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m')) gives?

Comment: `2020/12/11/20` is not a date, a date is a year, month and day. What is the fourth component?

Comment: When the string contains "year,month,day" (in that order) then you do not need a date, because BETWEEN does also work on strings (and will not be bothered by the connecting `/` signs (or `-` signs), but you should make sure the same separator is used in both strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a bad idea to store a date in a string instead of using the appropriate data type. You even call the column dt which suggests a datetime. This makes it harder to spot inappropriate handling.

Here

```
AND dt BETWEEN DATE '{START_DATE}' and DATE '{END_DATE}'
```

you compare a string with dates. Thus you rely on the DBMS guessing the string's date format correctly. Don't do this. Convert the string explicitely to a date, because you know the format. Or, as 'YYYY-MM-DD' is comparable, work with the strings right away:

```
AND dt BETWEEN '{START_DATE}' and '{END_DATE}'
```

Here

```
DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m')
```

you invoke a date function on a string. This means the DBMS must again guess your format, convert your string into a date accordingly and then invoke the function to convert the date into a string. Instead, just use the appropriate string function on the string:

```
SUBSTR(dt, 1, 7)
```

The complete query:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(dt, 1, 7) AS year_month,
    COUNT(*) AS total_visualization,
    COUNT(*) / CAST(SUBSTR('{END_DATE}', 9, 2)) AS INTEGER) AS average_dia
FROM 
    user.dashborad
WHERE 
    event = 'complete' 
    AND dt BETWEEN '{START_DATE}' and '{END_DATE}'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(dt, 1, 7)
ORDER BY SUBSTR(dt, 1, 7);
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much but can you explain me better about string function or send me a link to a documentation about it? I didn't know this way

Comment: If you just googled, you'd find https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html